# Promisify functions with callbacks in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class with multiple overloads on the methods accepting callbacks.
I want to make them `Promise` based instead, but I'm having trouble doing this in a type safe manner with TypeScript generics.

Basically the API is this:

```
class CallbackClient {
  method(req: Request, callback: (error: Error, response: Response) => void): void
  method(req: Request, options: Options, callback: (error: Error, response: Response) => void): void
}
```

and should become this:

```
class PromiseClient {
  method(req: Request): Promise<Response>
  method(req: Request, options: Options): Promise<Response>
}
```

But how do a define the `PromiseClient` as a generic type in TypeScript?
In pseudo code I want a type like this:

```
type PromiseClient<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: (args of T[P] without the callback) => Promise<response of T[P] in callback>
}
```

I got an implementation that makes this happen, but I loose type safety because of my inability to get this in place.

The function to map it is like this:

```
function toPromiseClient<T extends CallbackClient>(client: T): PromiseClient<T> {
  const promiseClient: PromiseClient<T> = {}
  Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(client))
    .forEach((functionName: string) => {
      const originalFunction = client[functionName as keyof T]
      if (!originalFunction) {
        return
      }
      promiseClient[functionName as keyof T] = (...args: any[]) => new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (args && args.length > 1 && typeof (args[args.length - 1]) === 'function') {
          reject(new Error('Use Promise API instead of callbacks'))
          return
        }
        originalFunction.call(client, ...args, (error: Error, res: any) => {
          if (error) {
            reject(error)
            return
          }
          resolve(res)
        })
      })
    })
  return promiseClient
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is partially possible in typescript 2.8 (unreleased yet, should be released in March 2018, you can get if via `npm install -g typescript@next`)

The solution:

```
declare class CallbackClient {
    method1(req: Request, options: Options, callback: (error: Error, response: Response) => void): void
    method1(req: Request, callback: (error: Error, response: Response) => void): void


    method2(req: Request, options: Options, callback: (error: Error, response: Response) => void): void

    method3(req: Request, options?: Options, callback?: (error: Error, response: Response) => void): void
}

type Promisify<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends (callback: (error: Error, response: infer TResponse) => void) => void ? () => Promise<TResponse> :
    T[P] extends (p1: infer P1, callback: (error: Error, response: infer TResponse) => void) => void ? (p1: P1) => Promise<TResponse> :
    T[P] extends (p1: infer P1, p2: infer P2, callback: (error: Error, response: infer TResponse) => void) => void ? (p1: P1, p2: P2) => Promise<TResponse> :
    T[P] extends (p1: infer P1, p2: infer P2, p3: infer P3, callback: (error: Error, response: infer TResponse) => void) => void ? (p1: P1, p2: P2, p3: P3) => Promise<TResponse> :
    never;
}

type PromiseClient = Promisify<CallbackClient>; 
// Will be equivalent to :
// type PromiseClient = {
//     method1: (p1: Request) => Promise<Response>; // Only one overload, not the second
//     method2: (p1: Request, p2: Options) => Promise<Response>;
//     method3: (p1: Request, p2: Options | undefined) => Promise<Response>;
// }
```

The solution above uses conditional types to extract parameter types from each  method of the original class, and then uses the types to create a new function type for the method that returns a promise.

The limitations:

1. It does not work for an arbitrary number of parameters, the above solution works for up to 3 parameters and the callback, but you can add more
2. The parameter names are lost
3. If parameters are optional they will become required with their type being `ArgType | undefined`
4. If there are multiple overloads of a method, only the one with the least parameters will make it into the result. In the above example, we only get `method1: (p1: Request) => Promise<Response>` we don't also get `method1: (p1: Request, p2: Options) => Promise<Response>` (and depending on the order of the overloads you might get strange results, it is quirky).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last limitation (4). Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @BjørnSørensen played around with it a bit more, added am example for limitation 4. Hope it clears things up, let me know if I can help with other info :)

Comment: I understand now. Your answer lead me to the right term as well: "conditional types" and my issue is actually described in this GH pull request: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496#issuecomment-366481789