# Change function return type while keeping parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Given a function with an arbitrary signature, is it possible in TypeScript type system to express a new function type with the same signature, but a different return type?

Getting the same type is easy with generics and type constraints (`T extends Function`). Conditional types with `infer` keyword allow one to extract the return type. But can something similar be done with the function's parameters?

Comment: You can use this approach, but it will not work with generic functions optional parameter are not well handled https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303695/promisify-functions-with-callbacks-in-typescript/49303971#49303971

Comment: I found a question I believe to be identical, If that answer does not satisfy you let me know and we can reopen this question or add clarifications on the other answer :)